# Nesting Array Values in a Json Output correctly

Tags: php, arrays, json

Right now I have something like this going on:

```
$items = $order->get_items();

$item_name = array();
$item_qty = array();
$item_price = array();
$item_sku = array();
    
foreach( $items as $key => $item){
    $item_name[] = $item['name'];
    $item_qty[] = $item['qty'];
    $item_price[] = $item['line_total'];
    
    $item_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product = new WC_Product($item_id);
    $item_sku[] = $product->get_sku();
}

$data = array(
        'receipt_type' => 101,
        'payment_type' => 1,
        'shop' => 171,
        'items' => [
            [
            'codigo' => implode(',', $item_sku),
            'cantidad' => implode(',', $item_qty),
            'concepto' => implode(',', $item_name),
            'precio' => implode(',', $item_price),
            
            ],
        ],
    );
```

This outputs something like:

```
{
"tipo_comprobante": 101,
"forma_pago": 1,
"sucursal": 171,
"moneda": "UYU",
"montos_brutos": 0,
"cliente": "-",
"items": [
    {
        "codigo": "SKU0001,SKU0002,SKU0003",
        "cantidad": "1,2,1",
        "concepto": "Producto 1,Producto 2,Producto 3",
        "precio": "200,890,900",
    }
]
```

}

But I need it to output like so:

```
{
"tipo_comprobante": 101,
"forma_pago": 1,
"sucursal": 171,
"moneda": "UYU",
"montos_brutos": 0,
"cliente": "-",
"items": [
    {
        "codigo": "SKU0001",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "concepto": "Producto 1",
        "precio": "200",
    },
    {
        "codigo": "SKU0002",
        "cantidad": "2",
        "concepto": "Producto 2",
        "precio": "890",
    },
    {
        "codigo": "SKU0003",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "concepto": "Producto 3",
        "precio": "900",
    }
]
```

}

How can this be achieved?  I've tried multiple things but not sure I understand how i can break apart the values and reformat.

Am i missing something?  Some formating Kung-fu would be most appreciated.

Thanx in advance, you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works since I can't test it atm but it should roughly look something like this. The easiest way is to add the "item" array data inside your foreach loop.

```
$items = $order->get_items();

$data = array(
    'receipt_type' => 101,
    'payment_type' => 1,
    'shop' => 171
);

$i = 0;

foreach( $items as $item){
    $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
    $item_sku = $product->get_sku();

    $data['items'][$i++] = array(            [
        'codigo' => $item_sku,
        'cantidad' => $item['qty'],
        'concepto' => $item['name'],
        'precio' => $item['line_total']
    );
}
```

EDIT: Sorry forgot to delete the implodes!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that'll work.

```
$items = $order->get_items();

$items_array = array(); 

$item_name = array();
$item_qty = array();
$item_price = array();
$item_sku = array();
    
foreach( $items as $key => $item){
    $item_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product = new WC_Product($item_id);

    $items_array[] = [
        'codigo' => $product->get_sku(),
        'cantidad' => $item['qty'],
        'concepto' => $item['name'],
        'precio' => $item['line_total'],

    ];
}

$data = array(
    'receipt_type' => 101,
    'payment_type' => 1,
    'shop' => 171,
    'items' => items_array,
);
```

Comment: This will require more memory than my answer since you're populating two different arrays with the same data.